# Oracle - String - Punctuation Formatting Function

Tags: string, oracle, function, plsql, punctuation

I have a `FUNCTION` that replaces multiple (consecutive) Horizontal Spaces within a `STRING` with a singular Horizontal Space;

e.g.

```
STR_ORIG = 'Hello    World'
STR_NEW  = 'Hello World'
```

The function is as follows;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CP_RDN_PUNCT(
  INS VARCHAR2)
 RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
 OUTSTR VARCHAR2(4000);
 STR VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
 STR := INS;
 WHILE (INSTR(STR,' ',1) > 0 )
 LOOP
  OUTSTR := OUTSTR || ' ' || SUBSTR(STR,1,INSTR(STR,' ',1) - 1);
  STR := TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM SUBSTR(STR,INSTR(STR,' ',1)));
 END LOOP;
OUTSTR := OUTSTR || ' ' || TRIM(STR);
RETURN TRIM(OUTSTR);
END CP_RDN_PUNCT;
```

However, I would like to expand on this `FUNCTION` so it is able to correct basic punctuation formatting (commas, full stops and parentheses). BUT, it's important that the FUNCTION continues to remove multiple (consecutive) Horizontal Spaces.

For example;

If `STR_ORIG = 'Hello , Marc'` the output would become `'Hello, Marc'`

If `STR_ORIG = 'Hello.Marc'` the output would become `'Hello. Marc'`

If `STR_ORIG = 'Hello(Marc )'` the output would become `'Hello (Marc)'`

The rules I would like to use are fairly basic:

```
Comma;...............One HORIZONTAL SPACE after a Comma.
                     No HORIZONTAL SPACE before a Comma.

Full Stop;...........One HORIZONTAL SPACE after a Full Stop.
                     No HORIZONTAL SPACE before a Full Stop.

Open Parenthesis;....No HORIZONTAL SPACE after an Open Parenthesis.
                     One HORIZONTAL SPACE before an Open Parenthesis.

Closed Parenthesis;..One HORIZONTAL SPACE after an Closed Parenthesis*.          
                     No HORIZONTAL SPACE before an Closed Parenthesis.
```

*Note: When a Comma or Full Stop is present directly after the Closed Parenthesis, instead of the 'One `HORIZONTAL SPACE`' rule it will use the 'No `HORIZONTAL SPACE`' rule.

I believe a `FUNCTION` is the best approach for this issue (I have explored using pure SQL (`REG_EXP`) but the code starts getting quite messy - primarily due to inconsistencies in the data). Also, if I wanted to add additional rules in the future (e.g. a rule for underscores), I'm assuming a `FUNCTION` would be easier to maintain. However, as always I am open to suggestions from the professionals.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more approach I could think of is to use an `associated array` to store the patterns and replacements instead of plain sql. Then in a loop apply each transformation on the string.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cp_rdn_punct2 (
    inp_pattern VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

    v_outstr   VARCHAR2(1000) := inp_pattern;
    TYPE v_astype IS
        TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40) INDEX BY VARCHAR(40);
    v_pat      v_astype;
    v_idx      VARCHAR2(40);

BEGIN
    v_pat(' *, *' ) := ', ';
    v_pat(' *\. *') := '. ';
    v_pat(' *\( *') := ' (';
    v_pat(' *\) *') := ') ';
    v_idx := v_pat.first;
    WHILE v_idx IS NOT NULL LOOP
        v_outstr := regexp_replace(v_outstr,v_idx,v_pat(v_idx) );
        v_idx := v_pat.next(v_idx);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN v_outstr;
END;
/
```

Comment: This is superb, @Kaushik Nayak! I really appreciate you taking the time to work on this - Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the function with a `REGEXP` than using `INSTR` , `SUBSTR`.

**Note:** This function does not consider multiple type of pattern appearing in the same string. So if "," and "."both appear it won't work. So, you can write all the transformation code required ,`EXCEPTION` handling etc  yourself to cover such scenarios. I have given you the idea as to how it can be done. You may have to rewrite with `IF THEN` or `CASE` blocks as I coded inside `with` clause for a PL/SQL like code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CP_RDN_PUNCT(
  inp_pattern VARCHAR2)
 RETURN VARCHAR2
AS 
outstr VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
with reg  ( pattern, regex ,replacement ) AS

(
    select ',' , ' *, *', ', ' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
    select '.' , ' *\. *', '. ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select '(' , ' *\( *', ' (' FROM DUAL 
  )
 SELECT
    TRIM(regexp_replace(rep,' *\) *',') ') ) INTO outstr
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            regexp_replace(inp_pattern,regex,replacement) rep
        FROM
            reg
        WHERE
            inp_pattern LIKE '%'
            || pattern
            || '%'
    );

RETURN outstr;

END;
/
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, Kaushik Nayak - I’ll test shortly. Much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, this compiles OK, but upon testing, it results in `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`. Testing before posting - what a great concept! :-)